# Turn On/Off Hardware modules in Core Location framework

Tags: iphone, swift, core-location

As we all know `Core Location` framework uses all available in iPhone onboard hardware, including Accelerometer, Magnetometer, Gyroscope, Barometer, GPS, and Bluetooth for iBeacon.

```
// Here are CL classes that use iPhone's hardware

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }
var altitude: CLLocationDistance { get }
var horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy { get }
var speed: CLLocationSpeed { get }
```

**Is it possible to turn each of these hardware modules on/off programmatically via Swift?**

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to directly control the individual modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it’s not possible to directly control the individual hardware modules.